# Handlebars.js - concatenating an arbitrary string within an expression

Tags: javascript, templates, mustache, handlebars.js

An example:

Using handlebars.js if I wanted to do append an "@" to a username I would do this:

```
@{{username}}
```

However, what if I want to use a custom helper and have it applied to the entire block of text (including the "@") and not just the expression? Something like this...

```
handlebars.registerHelper('color', function(text) {
    return text.red;
});

{{color "@"username}}
```

The above template is invalid, but you get the idea...

Answer (score 6):

You can do this, for example:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <ul>
        {{#each links}}
        <li><a href="{{ url }}">{{{color prefix title}}}</a></li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
<script>
Handlebars.registerHelper("color", function(prefix, title) {
    return '<span style="color: blue">' + (prefix ? prefix : "@") + title + '</span>';
}); // "@" is the default prefix

source = document.getElementById("template").innerHTML;
template = Handlebars.compile(source);
document.write(template({
    links: [
        {title: "prologin", prefix: "#", link: "http://prologin.org"},
        {title: "1.2.1", prefix: "§", link: "#paragraph-121"},
        {title: "jjvie", link: "http://twitter.com/jjvie"},
    ]
}));
</script>
```

`<span class="username"></span>` or `<hl></hl>` would be even better.